How to create an ES module npm package with sass?
When I create a npm package, I use some sass to style the components.
When I build the package, I choose ES module. So it generates:
dist
  my-component.es.js
  index.css

My question is when I use this package, I will write code like:
import { Component } from 'my-component';

But this doesn't include the css files. I can import it in this way:
import "my-component/dist/index.css";

But it looks weired. What is the recommended way to generate an ES module package with sass?
Or is it normal to import the css in this way?

If you don’t like the css import then inline the css. Importing css files happens a lot, either refactor to avoid or worry less about it. Depends on your goals and what tradeoffs you want to make.
